# How to decrypt a shell script with sh.x extension in linux?

Tags: encryption

I have a shell script file like example.sh.x
How can I decrypt it in linux? is there any command?

Comment: How comes you think it's encrypted?

Comment: Also, without loss of generality, encryption is hard to reverse without knowing the secret. --- That is the job of encryption, after all.

However, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `.x` is not a common file extansion that you will find on Linux.

On the other hand, `.xz` is a common compressed file format. If you look into a compressed file, the contents look random, just like an encrypted file. The difference is that for a compressed file you don't need a password to uncompress it.

A good way to see what kind of data you'dealing with is the `file` utility. Please run `file example.sh.x` and edit your question to add the output of that command.

Some examples:

```
> file foo.xz 
foo.xz: XZ compressed data
> file ttktest.py 
ttktest.py: a /usr/bin/env python script, ASCII text executable
```

Another way to look at files (epsecially if `file` doesn't recognize them) is to use `hexdump`. For example, running hexdump on an `xz` compressed file would give:

```
> hexdump -C -n 16 glas.lam.xz
00000000  fd 37 7a 58 5a 00 00 04  e6 d6 b4 46 02 00 21 01  |.7zXZ......F..!.|
00000010
```

Run `hexdump -C -n 16 example.sh.x` and add the output to your question.

---

If the file `example.sh.x` really is encrypted, then you'll need to know *how* (which program/algorithm) it was encrypted, and you will probably need the password.

Answer (score 0):

shc is a shell script compiler for Unix-like operating systems, The Shell Script Compiler (SHC) encodes and encrypts shell scripts into executable binaries.

so after looking in to this i found out that there's a old project https://github.com/yanncam/UnSHc but theres a message on the read me saying

> Due to the many problems since shc 4.0.3, there seems to be a need for clarification. In shc 4.0.3 many structural changes have been incorporated, so that shc now makes use of various security mechanisms provided by the linux-kernel itself. Therefore, it is now almost impossible to extract the original shell script at all with current UnSHc version, if the new shc version was used. This requires a more in-depth approach, which means that a modified bash or a modified linux-kernel is needed to bypass the security measures.

so if the script is compiled with new shc versions it wont be possible to extract the script.

But there's another possible way to get a idea of what is executing on the script you can run a program like pspy https://github.com/DominicBreuker/pspy ( this tool lets you monitor linux processors )

Then let the program run and execute the script, and you should be able to see what the script is doing + dump the code of the script.